# Ignoring backslash and double quotes in F#

Tags: f#

How do we ignore backslashes in a string?
I tried this but it dosen't work:

```
let str2 = @"I igonore \ \ \ / / / / backsalshes"
printfn "%s" str2
```

Also, I thought ignoring double quotes in a string is as follow:

```
let str3 = """ "I ig""onore double quotes and backslasehes " """
printfn "%s" str3
```

Again, It printed a string with the double quote 'ig""onore'.
What is wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings

Comment: My answer explains what you are misunderstanding about the `@` syntax and the `"""` syntax for strings. But what I don't know is: why do you want to ignore backslashes? What is the problem you're trying to solve, where having backslashes "disappear" would be useful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` sign doesn't "ignore" backslashes in the sense that they don't appear in the string, it simply treats them as *normal* characters, instead of as characters with a special meaning. E.g.,

```
let s1 = "\n"  # A single newline character
let s2 = @"\n" # Two characters, a backslash and then a lowercase n
```

Likewise, the triple-quote syntax doesn't make `"` characters *disappear*, it simply lets you embed single `"` characters, or pairs of them, in the string without having to jump through syntax hoops to do so. If it make `"` characters *disappear* in a string, it wouldn't be very useful.